# python regex: how to replace all png files in string with prefix?

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm getting a long stream of random strings containing png files from the wild.

ex.

```
"2016.png random characters vjifj903%.png unpredictable characters"
```

I want to replace all .png files with a prefix `myserver.com/` so

```
"myserver.com/2016.png random characters myserver.com/vjifj903%.png unpredictable characters"
```

Is there any way to do this so that it's not case insensitive and it will be able to perform this feature?

I tried

`str.replace(".png","myserver.com/");` but I don't know how to make it appear as a prefix, this just adds a suffix.

Comment: Would any of the png file names have spaces in them?

Comment: You tagged the question with `regex` but you are using plain old `replace` – a simple string function. Did you try a regex solution?

Comment: @nicarus it's possible yes as I dont control the text coming in

Comment: What's wrong with `if ".png" in filename: filename = "my server.com/" + filename`?

Comment: @ILovePython So, how would you know which text is part of the file name and which is just "random characters"?

Comment: there is a distinct space around each filename or separated by comma...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Regex:

```
(?<=\b)[^\s]+?\.png
```

## Substitution:

```
myserver.com/\0
```

## Usage:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(?<=\b)[^\s]+?\.png')
test_str = u"2016.png random characters vjifj903%.png unpredictable characters"
subst = u"myserver.com/\0"

result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```

This makes the `result` variable:

```
myserver.com/2016.png random characters myserver.com/vjifj903%.png unpredictable characters
```

## Demo:

https://regex101.com/r/pJ0oS8/4

## Explanation:

Find a word boundary, then find the preceding non white space characters up until `.png`.  Then substitute `myserver.com/` before the match.

Answer (score 0):

This will work if you won't have spaces in file names:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import re

prefix = 'myserver.com/'
s = "2016.png random characters vjifj903%.png unpredictable characters"

print(re.sub(r'([^\s]*\.png)', prefix + r'\1', s, re.I))
```

Output:

```
myserver.com/2016.png random characters myserver.com/vjifj903%.png unpredictable characters
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generator:

```
>>> string = "2016.png random characters vjifj903%.png unpredictable characters"
>>> print(" ".join(("myserver.com/" * word.endswith(".png")) + word for word in string.split())
myserver.com/2016.png random characters myserver.com/vjifj903%.png unpredictable characters
```

If you want the words to be separated in the string, then it's simpler:

```
>>> string = "2016.png random characters vjifj903%.png unpredictable characters"
>>> print [("myserver.com/" * word.endswith(".png")) + word for word in string.split()]
['myserver.com/2016.png', 'random', 'characters', 'myserver.com/vjifj903%.png', 'unpredictable', 'characters']
```